# Managing remote server connections via Nautilus

Tags: command-line, nautilus, ssh, ftp

Is there any way to manage remote server credentials while using *Nautilus* remote server connect feature? The *Recent Servers* works for couple of connections, but not for 20+.

Also it seems that if I have two different FTP accounts in one server/IP address, then the last connection will replace the previous one, both directories shows the most recent connection to that server. Is that a bug or am I missing something here?

Can I write a simple shell script that connects to the server -- SSH/SFTP/FTP, and then opens up the Nautilus for the ease of use?

P.S. Currently running on Ubuntu 14.10.

P.P.S. Haven't tested *Filezilla* on Ubuntu yet, but generally it isn't able to automatically upload a file after it is opened up from server and is locally modified, unless you confirm a dialog box -- *WinSCP* was working like a charm. Same problem with *gFTP*. That's why I'm trying to manage all of the connections via Nautilus, instead of Filezilla, gFTP or similar tools.

**Update #1**

Since I couldn't find any solution that fits my needs, I decided to `mount` the remote server via `curlftpfs` until I find a more managed solution:

```
sudo curlftpfs -o allow_other user:pass@1.2.3.4 /local/path
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [Desktop Shortcut File](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles) and place them on `$HOME/.local/share/applications/` your keyring will still manage the passwords so no plain text passwords.

Bellow is the file content. Name it `what_ever_you_like.desktop` and add execution permission, place it in the above path for easy menu access. For SSH terminal aliases are probably better.

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
Exec=nautilus ftp://ftp.mysite.com/public_html
Path=
Name=A meaningful name
Comment=FTP site Access
Icon=folder-remote
```

PS: About the 'Nautilus bug' I don't believe it's bug just an unconsidered Use Case.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to remote hosts in Nautilus using this method:

1. Connect to remote host
2. Host address: username@ftp.host.com
3. Type password in, save it forever.
4. After connecting, save the place with Ctrl-D to the Bookmarks, rename it to Host FTP.
5. Try unmount and remount it with the shortcut created in Bookmarks in step 4.

edit: with this method you can use multiple accounts at the same hosting company